# Center Text in View- Doesn't Center

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a Swift Playground and would like to center a label. However, when I do `label.center = view.center` the text will go off to a weird place, [as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLW2h.png) . (It is the one on the far right; the others are centered with CGPoints.) Here is the viewDidLoad regarding my view and label:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 186/255.0, green: 198/255.0, blue: 196/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:222/255, green:225/255, blue:227/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "To play, make the gestures that the app speaks and then press the green check when you are done."
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = font
    label.center = view.center
    label.textColor = UIColor(red:102/255, green: 121/255, blue: 118/255, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(self.label)
```

Other people have said it worked on their computers but I have tried on 2 different Macs and it didn't work. Since I'm working with Playgrounds, I cannot use the storyboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in time that `viewDidLoad` is called views aren't resized correctly, you need to center your label when they are. For example in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    label.center = view.center
}
```